# Transition Background-Image

Tags: html, css, background, transition, smoothing

I'm a bit of a newbie to the world of web programming, but I'm trying to develop a webpage that will transition from a black and white version of a photo to a normal color version of a photo when the page loads.

After trying a lot of different things, the best I could do was make the colored version appear instantly. I also tried to play around with JQuery a bit, but for some reason, I couldn't get the page to load correctly. It stayed on the black and white version, rather than transition to the normal version.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bad+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>UCLA Wushu - Home</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("html").animate({'background' : 'url(images/home_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed'}, 'slow');
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="middleBar">
<strong>
<a href="index.html">My Portal</a>
</strong>
<div id="enter"><a href="announcements.html">Enter</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The relevant CSS is as follows (I copy and pasted in order to stretch the background image effectively into the browser):

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
html { 
  background: url(images/home_background_bw.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Please let me know if there is a way to smoothly transition from black and white into color using this format. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution without use of any saturation plugin etc, is to put div with colored image and zero opacity right after the body tag and then animate opacity of that div to 100%.

Part of your HTML:

```
...
<title>UCLA Wushu - Home</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#colored-bg").animate({
           opacity: 100
        }, 'slow');
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="colored-bg"></div>
<div id="container">
<div id="middleBar">
...
```

CSS:

```
#colored-bg { 
  background: url(images/home_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: ~"alpha(opacity=@{0})"; // IE
  // following will strecth the element from corner to corner
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand what you want, you can try to use for example

```
-webkit-transition: background-color 2s linear;
-moz-transition: background-color 2s linear;
-ms-transition: background-color 2s linear;
-o-transition: background-color 2s linear;
transition: background-color 2s linear;
```

Like that: http://jsfiddle.net/guillaumek/CcNHv/

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MLdw4/)

It uses two images one black and while and another color. Color image is hidden behind black and white image.

Then onclick the black and white image fades out to reveal color image.

Check it out.

HTML:

```
<div id="color">
    <div id="blackAndWhite"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#blackAndWhite").click(function(){
$(this).fadeOut(5000);
});
```

Hope it helps!